# ListView SectionIndexer's box is transparent

Tags: android, listview, colors, indexer

In my app I'm using a listview with a section indexer that displays the letter of the current selection. It's fine on a lot of devices, but when I use my app on a Galaxy Tab running Android 3.2 the letter is displayed without the little box. I don't know how to make it appear or change the color of this letter.

I tried to use `android:textColorPrimary` but I didn't find how to use it and I find no sample.

To see my problem, below is a screenshot. If you look carefully, the letter `G` is in white above the second element of the list.

[image: Problem screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a strange answer, because I fixed it, but I'm not sure why. When I set `FastScrollEnable = true` later than in the contructor of my derived `ListView` I get this behaviour aswell. Although, my letter is almost completly off the screen.

I'll probably get downvotes for this answer, but it saved me after 6 hours of prodding around. I noticed it when I removed my prototype code from our main classes to change the `FastScrollEnable` from outside.